# Struts 2 String to Double Conversion on ValueStack

Tags: struts2

I am new to Struts2 and following "Struts2 in Action". I have one question

My book says if you are using data-type different then String , you need to tell compiler that its no longer String and define property file named  `DataTransferTest-conversion.properties` with `Element-weights=java.lang.Double` in case of List (i.e you are using Double type in your List).

However , when i did this practically , i didn't specified my property file. Still , its working. I don't know!! Why?

I am attaching my code layers. Please look

**Action Class**

```java
public class ListExampleAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<ListExample> {
    ListExample example = new ListExample();
    private List<ListExample> listExample;
    private Double x;

//Getters Setters//

@Action(value="/ListExample", results={
            @Result(name="success",location="/listExampleDisplay.jsp"),

        })
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return "success";

    }
```

**Display Action Class( just to return jsp)**

```java
public class DisplayListExampleAction extends ActionSupport{

    @Action(value="/ListExampleAction", results={
            @Result(name="success",location="/listExample.jsp"),

        })
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return "success";

    }


}
```

**List Example Class for List Type**

```java
public class ListExample{
    private String firstName;
    private Double age;

//getter/setters//

}
```

**listExample.jsp**

```jsp
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Struts </h1>
<form action="ListExample">
// For List
<s:textfield name="listExample.firstName" label="User 1 Name"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield name="listExample.age" label="User 1 Age"></s:textfield>
// For x varaible in Action Class 
<s:textfield name="x" label="x"></s:textfield>
<s:submit></s:submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**listExampleDisplay.jsp**

```jsp
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Struts</h1>
 // For List
        Users List =
        <s:iterator value="listExample">
            <s:property value="firstName" />
            <s:property value="age" />
        </s:iterator>
        <br>
// For x varaible in Action Class 
        <s:property value="x"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Output:**

> UserAge =21
>   User Name = Saurabh
>
> x = 21.0

Answer (score 0):

Because the book is really old and covers only Struts 2.0.

Back then many types *did* require a conversion specification.

Later versions improved their ability to automatically convert between types through introspection.

IIRC that earlier book also didn't cover the annotations covered by some later books.

Comment: please refer me book if its possible

Comment: @user3817863 [there was an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24571518/1654265) (that romanc felt the urge to delete), explaining which parts of that (and others) book are still covered, and which ones are completely unusable nowadays. Unluckily, you need 10k rep to see it since it's deleted :/

Comment: @AndreaLigios In fairness, my book covered the annotations and didn't discuss the Dojo tags ;)